# How to grab the youtube username of currently logged user

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api

I am coding a application , where i need the youtube username of currently logged user on youtube.com. Can anyone give some kind of hint/tutorial ?

Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: You should have it when logging in a user with a password via OAuth.

Comment: There is no way to do this without integrating OAuth to the flow of your application.